# apex trigger not updating some of the time (CASE object, update on FeedItem update)

Tags: apex, trigger, case

I have a script where if someone puts a chatter on an existing SF POST object it updates a timestamp.  For some reason this doesn't work about 10% of the time, and it's only for ONE of my employees.  My code is below:

```
trigger LastTouched on FeedComment(after insert, after update){

List<Case> updates = new List<case>();
Set<Id>feedItemIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Id> feedItemList = new List<id>();

// We'll narrow down our user list here, and use a Map, so their Ids are easy to get to.
Map<id,user> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Support_Team_Member__c = true]); 


// first loop through to get the FeedItemIds
for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
    if(userMap.containsKey(fc.InsertedById)){ // only add them to the list if they are the right user
        feedItemIds.add(fc.FeedItemId);
    }
}

// Next, query the Cases using a nested query.  This lets us hop across two layers of parent/child relationship in one query.
if(!feedItemIds.isEmpty()){
    for(Case c : [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM FeedItem WHERE Id IN :feedItemIds)]){
        // Add the cases to the update list
        updates.add(new Case(id = c.Id, Last_Updated_By_Support__c = System.now()));
    }
}

// now we run the update.
update updates;
}
```

When running the query used above, I get back her user object

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Support_Team_Member__c = true
```

Is there something I'm missing?  I can't understand an edge case where this would work sometimes and not others...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you consider both `FeedComment` and `FeedItem`? They are both related. `FeedComment` is obviously a comment, but `FeedItem` is the initial post. Or do you only want the Last Update By Support field to only be updated with comments and not initial posts?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a soql to get the case ids, I would try

```
Boolean feedCommentIsRelatedToCase = fc.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Schema.Case.SObjectType;

if(userMap.containsKey(fc.InsertedById) && feedCommentIsRelatedToCase) {
   updates.add(new Case(id = fc.ParentId, Last_Updated_By_Support__c = System.now()));
}
```

That way you get rid of an unnecessary soql and you don't need to rely on what's returned from a soql to update the desired data.

Comment: Sorry about the long delay in getting back to this, but I implemented this and it seems as though this issue is still coming up; which means that the first query must be SOMEHOW failing, which doesn't seem possible because the trigger is on feedcomment   and running the SOQL query returns the user in question.

Comment: @A_Elric why not try using `CreatedById` in the check?